# Access individual bits of a variable

Tags: pic, c, optimization, bit-bang

I'm making a code on a PIC16F628A running at 4 MHz that receives the serial bitstream of a 433 MHz remote. The catch here is that I'm forced to do some rather questionable stuff because the pin assignation on the PCB this uC is used was vaguely done, and there is no way of using the most useful modules. This "questionable stuff" is the use of timer2 (the other timers are already in use).

So far (by transmitting the codes at a slower rate) I've been able to completely receive the whole bit stream, only adding a extra 0 at the MSB. The thing now is that I'm trying to optimize the prototype code to be able to merge it to the main code where all other stuff is done:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SYNCq 15
#define UART_TRIS_RX     TRISBbits.TRISB1
#define UART_TRIS_TX     TRISBbits.TRISB2


typedef union {
    uint16_t REG;

    struct {
        unsigned RX : 1;    // Bit de estado de pin Rx
        unsigned RXp : 1;   // Bit de estado previo de pin Rx
        unsigned DONE : 1;  // Bit de fin de recepcion
        unsigned MTCH : 1;  // Bit de control conocido
        unsigned CNT : 5;   // Cuenta total de bits recividos
    } REGbits;
} customRFREG;

volatile customRFREG RFREGu; // Registro de modulo RF 433MHz
#define RFREG RFREGu.REG
#define RFREGbits RFREGu.REGbits
int8_t RXc = 0;             // Cuenta de pulsos
__bit rcvd_key[32] = {0};     // Registro de recepcion

char buffer[32] = {0};
char buff[38] = {0};

void UARTinit(const long, const unsigned char);
void UARTsendString(const char *, const unsigned char);

void main(void) {
    TRISA = 0xFF;
    TRISB = 0x00;
    PORTA = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0x00;
    
    RFREG = 0x0000;
    RXc = 0;

    INTCON = 0xC0;
    PIE1 = 0x02;
    T2CON = 0x00;
    PR2 = 111;
    UARTinit(9600, 1);
    UARTsendString("PIC OK\n\r", 20);
    while (1) {
        if (PORTAbits.RA4 && !T2CONbits.TMR2ON) { 
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;
        }
        if (RFREGbits.DONE) { 
            RFREGbits.RX = RFREGbits.CNT = 0;
            RFREGbits.DONE = T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
            RFREGbits.CNT = RXc = 0;
            RFREGbits.RXp = 0;
            sprintf(buff, "%s\n\r", rcvd_key);
            UARTsendString(buff, sizeof buff);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void __interrupt() isr() {
    if (PIR1bits.TMR2IF) {
        RFREGbits.RX = PORTAbits.RA4;
        if (!RFREGbits.RX) {
            if (RFREGbits.RXp) {
                if (RXc > 0) { //0
                    PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;
                    rcvd_key[RFREGbits.CNT] = 48;
                } else { //1
                    PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
                    rcvd_key[RFREGbits.CNT] = 49;
                }
                RXc = 0;
                RFREGbits.CNT++;
            }
            RXc--;
            PORTBbits.RB3 = 0;
        } else {
            RXc++;
            PORTBbits.RB3 = 1;
        }
        if (RXc < -20){
            RFREGbits.DONE = 1;
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        RFREGbits.RXp = RFREGbits.RX;
        PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0;
        PORTBbits.RB5 = !PORTBbits.RB5;
    }
}

// RCREG: EUSART Receive Data Register
// OERR: Receive Overrun error (FIFO out of space). Clearing this bit is mandatory when this error ocurrs (reset USART)
// CREN: Continous Receive enable Bit
// FERR: Framing Error (stop bit missing)(not required for normal operation)

void UARTinit(const long baud_rate, const unsigned char BRGH) {
    // Calculate BRG
    if (BRGH == 0) {
        SPBRG = _XTAL_FREQ / (64 * baud_rate) - 1;
        TXSTAbits.BRGH = 0;
    } else {
        SPBRG = _XTAL_FREQ / (16 * baud_rate) - 1;
        TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
    }

    // TXSTA register
    TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0; // 8-bit transmission
    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1; // Enable transmission
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // Asynchronous mode

    // RCSTA register
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // Enable serial port
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0; // 8-bit reception
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Enable continuous reception
    RCSTAbits.FERR = 0; // Disable framing error
    RCSTAbits.OERR = 0; // Disable overrun error

    // Set up direction of RX/TX pins
    UART_TRIS_RX = 1;
    UART_TRIS_TX = 0;
}

void UARTsendString(const char* str, const unsigned char max_length) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < max_length && str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        while (TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0); // Wait for buffer to be empty
        TXREG = str[i];
    }
}
```

I think the code itself is pretty well laid out, and there is no need to optimize it (I think). All the uart stuff is going to get deleted on the production code. It’s just here for debugging. The thing is that currently I'm waisting 32 bytes (excluding all the UART stuff) to only use the LSB of each one. The idea here is to find a way to use the least amount of bytes to store the code the remote sends. I already tried to use some bitwise operators to store everything in one `uint32_t` (`rcvd_key += 1 << RFREGbits.CNT;`), but it seems like it takes way too much time for the uC to do that kind of operation mid-interrupt (where the interrupt occurs every 100 µs), so maybe the only way of doing it is writing bit by bit. I've also been playing a bit with bit-fields and I have not found a way to use any of that stuff to my advantage. Also, I tried to use a `__bit` array, just to get the disappointing: `newmain.c:35:15: error: array of __bit type`.

Is there any other way of doing the same thing as the code is doing but instead of using 32 bytes use only 4?

Comment: I would use an assembly routine. Using C on a mid-range 8-bit PIC is a bit questionable unless you have speed and  memory to burn.

Comment: WHy are you using 32-bit integers on an 8-bit computer? Especially since you need only 1 bit.

Comment: IIRC most PIC chips do 1 instruction every 4 clock cycles, that means you have room for about 100 instructions per bit. Not terrible, but also not a lot of room for waste.

Comment: @RussellH The bit stream that the remote sends is a 24+4 bit code. There are no 28 bit variables so i have to go with a 32 bit variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the array of `__bit`, you can use a single 32-bit variable.

However, as you found already, it might take too much time to shift the 1-bit each time by the current index.

Instead, shift the variable just by 1 bit each time:

```c
uint32_t rcvd_key;

void __interrupt() isr() {
    if (PIR1bits.TMR2IF) {
        RFREGbits.RX = PORTAbits.RA4;
        if (!RFREGbits.RX) {
            if (RFREGbits.RXp) {
                rcvd_key <<= 1;
                if (RXc > 0) { //0
                    PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;
                    // nothing to do on rcvd_key, a zero bit is already shifted in
                } else { //1
                    PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
                    rcvd_key |= 1;
                }
                RXc = 0;
                RFREGbits.CNT++;
            }
            RXc--;
            PORTBbits.RB3 = 0;
        } else {
            RXc++;
            PORTBbits.RB3 = 1;
        }
        if (RXc < -20){
            RFREGbits.DONE = 1;
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        RFREGbits.RXp = RFREGbits.RX;
        PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0;
        PORTBbits.RB5 = !PORTBbits.RB5;
    }
}
```

Your debug output needs to be adjusted. With standard C, you will want to use hex output.

```c
// ...
            sprintf(buff, "%08lX\n\r", rcvd_key);
// ...
```

*Note: I am not familiar with the specific compiler (or more exactly: the library) for your target. Some implementations know the format specifier `"%b"` for binary output.*